# Why Selenium robot framework is very slow in IE browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, robotframework

I have updated IE driver and tried using css too instaed of ids or xpath, still Robot framework is very slow in IE.
Total time taken in chrome for 10 test cases : 30 mins
Total time taken in IE for 10 test cases : 45 mins.

Is there anyway to increase the performance in IE?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no easy way to increase the performance. It has nothing to do with the robot framework. The selenium IE driver is the slowest webdriver out there by far, and it gets very little developer resources. I'm not sure if it's the driver or IE itself that's slow, though I know that the watin driver runs a little faster than the selenium one.

What I recommend to people is to run the bulk of your tests on firefox or chrome if at all possible, and then just a few IE tests to test basic capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try is avoiding the usage of XPath locators. XPaths are processed natively in most browsers, but not Internet Explorer.